# Getting error when trying to run Hadoop 2.4.0 (-bash: bin/start-all.sh: No such file or directory)

Tags: hadoop, configuration, installation

I am doing the following to install and run Hadoop on my Mac:

First I install HomeBrew as the Package Manager

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Then I install Hadoop using the Brew command:

```
brew install hadoop
```

Then the following:

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.2/libexec

export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
```

Then I configure Hadoop by adding the following to proper .xml files:

core-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:9001</value>
</property>
```

I then Enable SSH to localhost:

```
System Preferences > Sharing > “Remote Login” is checked.

ssh-keygen -t rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I then Format Hadoop filesystem:

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

And then Start Hadoop (or at least try...this is where I get the error)

```
bin/start-all.sh
```

I get the error -bash: bin/start-all.sh: No such file or directory.

The one "odd" thing I did during setup was, since there is no longer a mapred-site.xml file in 2.4.0, I simply copied the mapred-site.xml.template file to my desktop, renamed it to mapred-site.xml, and put that new copy in the folder. I also tried running without any mapred-site.xml configuration but I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK , brew installs hadoop-2.4.0 by default.
 See here https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/hadoop.rb
And in hadoop2.x there is no `start-all.sh` file in `bin` folder. It is moved to `sbin`. Also you need some more configurations. These links may be useful : 
http://codesfusion.blogspot.in/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/